# INVALID_REQUEST_PARAMETER on listStatus

Tags: curl, docusignapi

I am trying to query Docusign to get a status of a set of envelopes but I am getting the `INVALID_REQUEST_PARAMETER` error.

Here is the curl request I am making

```
curl -X PUT \
  https://na2.docusign.net/restapi/v2/accounts/XXXXX/envelopes/status \
  -H 'Accept: application/json' \
  -H 'Content-Type: application/json' \
  -H 'X-DocuSign-Authentication: { ... }' \
  -d '{
    "envelopeIds": [
        "SOME ENVELOPE ID",
        "ANOTHER ENVELOPE ID"
    ]
  }'
```

Here is the full error I am getting

```
{
    "errorCode": "INVALID_REQUEST_PARAMETER",
    "message": "The request contained at least one invalid parameter. Query parameter 'from_date' must be set to a valid DateTime, or 'envelope_ids' or 'transaction_ids' must be specified."
}
```

According to the [documentation](https://developers.docusign.com/esign-rest-api/reference/Envelopes/Envelopes/listStatus#examples) if I include an array of `envelopeIds` this should work. It looks very similar to the example they have on that documentation page.

I know the error messages says to use `envelope_ids` so I tried that and got the same error.

What am I doing wrong here?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you want to pass envelopeIds in the requestBody then in the URL you need to set a query parameter as `envelope_ids=request_body`, so your complete URI will look like below:

```
PUT /restapi/v2/accounts/<accountId>/envelopes/status?envelope_ids=request_body
```

then you can pass requestBody as below:

```
{
    "envelopeIds": ["SOME ENVELOPE ID",
    "ANOTHER ENVELOPE ID"]
}
```

Comment: Ahh that did it! Thank you, Amit! I didn't see that mentioned on the documentation page, how did you know to do that?

Comment: Glad it worked! I work for DocuSign so I knew the answer

Comment: I gotcha. Well, I have one other quick question if you don't mind. Do you know how can include the individual recipient statuses in the response as well? In the example at the bottom of the doc page, it shows the response including that info but the response I get only includes the URI to retrieve the recipient info.

Comment: Please create a new qs in new post with detailed explanation, and SO members will try to resolve it.

Comment: Yeah, I can do that!

Comment: in case anyone stumbles upon this question with the same question here is the link to that question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50646664/liststatus-endpoint-include-recipient-status-in-response

Answer (score 0):

Additionally  you can also specify from_date as parameter as well

```
https://demo.docusign.net/restapi/v2/accounts/xxxxxx/envelopes/status?from_date=01/01/2019
```

Comment: Added thinking it'll help someone who wants to get list of envelopes without envelope ids

Answer (score 0):

Based on this [doc](https://developers.docusign.com/docs/esign-rest-api/reference/envelopes/envelopes/liststatuschanges/), you must provide `from_date` or `envelopeIds`.

I cannot find an api to get all envelopes. This is a workaround:

```
https://demo.docusign.net/restapi/v2/accounts/xxxxxx/envelopes?from_date=1990-01-01&status=created
```