# listStatus endpoint include recipient status in response

Tags: curl, docusignapi

Is there a way to include the recipient statuses in the response body for the listStatus endpoint?

Here is the curl request I am making

```
curl -X PUT \
  https://na2.docusign.net/restapi/v2/accounts/XXXXX/envelopes/status?envelope_ids=request_body \
  -H 'Accept: application/json' \
  -H 'Content-Type: application/json' \
  -H 'X-DocuSign-Authentication: { ... }' \
  -d '{
    "envelopeIds": [
        "SOME ENVELOPE ID",
        "ANOTHER ENVELOPE ID"
    ]
  }'
```

Here is the result I am getting

```
{
    "resultSetSize": "76",
    "totalSetSize": "76",
    "startPosition": "0",
    "endPosition": "75",
    "nextUri": "",
    "previousUri": "",
    "envelopes": [
        {
            "status": "sent",
            "documentsUri": "/envelopes/XXXX/documents",
            "recipientsUri": "/envelopes/XXXX/recipients",
            "attachmentsUri": "/envelopes/XXXX/attachments",
            "envelopeUri": "/envelopes/XXXX",
            "envelopeId": "XXXX",
            "customFieldsUri": "/envelopes/XXXX/custom_fields",
            "notificationUri": "/envelopes/12da3965-99cb-4c2d-9d3d-587a32fca118/notification",
            "statusChangedDateTime": "2017-08-07T14:34:38.4530000Z",
            "documentsCombinedUri": "/envelopes/XXXX/documents/combined",
            "certificateUri": "/envelopes/XXXX/documents/certificate",
            "templatesUri": "/envelopes/XXXX/templates"
        },
        ...
    ]
}
```

In the [documentation page](https://developers.docusign.com/esign-rest-api/reference/Envelopes/Envelopes/listStatus#examples), it shows an example response that includes

```
{
    "resultSetSize": "76",
    "totalSetSize": "76",
    "startPosition": "0",
    "endPosition": "75",
    "nextUri": "",
    "previousUri": "",
    "envelopes": [
        {
            "status": "sent",
            "documentsUri": "/envelopes/XXXX/documents",
            "recipientsUri": "/envelopes/XXXX/recipients",
            "attachmentsUri": "/envelopes/XXXX/attachments",
            "envelopeUri": "/envelopes/XXXX",
            "envelopeId": "XXXX",
            "customFieldsUri": "/envelopes/XXXX/custom_fields",
            "notificationUri": "/envelopes/12da3965-99cb-4c2d-9d3d-587a32fca118/notification",
            "statusChangedDateTime": "2017-08-07T14:34:38.4530000Z",
            "documentsCombinedUri": "/envelopes/XXXX/documents/combined",
            "certificateUri": "/envelopes/XXXX/documents/certificate",
            "templatesUri": "/envelopes/XXXX/templates",
            "recipients": {
              "signers": [
                {
                   "status": "sent",
                   ...
                }
              ]
            },
        },
        ...
    ]
}
```

I am not sure what I need to do to my original request to includes that `recipients` section in the response. Does anyone know if I am missing some kind of url param or body param or something?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is not possible in the [Envelopes: listStatus](https://docs.docusign.com/esign/restapi/Envelopes/Envelopes/listStatus/#/definitions/Envelopes) endpoint, it seems the response which you are seeing in sample JSON is autocreated by Swagger for the `Envelope` class. If you want to see all the details in one call then you need to make such call for each envelope using below endpoint,

```
/restapi/v2/accounts/{{AccountIdVal}}/envelopes/{envelopeId}?include=custom_fields,recipients,tabs&advanced_update=true
```

Comment: You are killing it with these questions Amit :)